# Problem compiling QGIS against trunk - georeferencer

Tags: qgis

I got problems compiling QGIS (trunk) this morning. The georeferencer seems to be the source of the problem:

```
[ 81%] Building CXX object src/plugins/georeferencer/CMakeFiles/georefplugin.dir/qgsgeorefplugingui.cpp.o
/usr/local/src/Quantum-GIS/src/plugins/georeferencer/qgsgeorefplugingui.cpp: In member function ‘void QgsGeorefPluginGui::createActions()’:
/usr/local/src/Quantum-GIS/src/plugins/georeferencer/qgsgeorefplugingui.cpp:864:3: error: ‘mActionLocalHistogramStretch’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/src/Quantum-GIS/src/plugins/georeferencer/qgsgeorefplugingui.cpp:868:3: error: ‘mActionFullHistogramStretch’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/src/Quantum-GIS/src/plugins/georeferencer/qgsgeorefplugingui.cpp: In member function ‘void QgsGeorefPluginGui::addRaster(QString)’:
/usr/local/src/Quantum-GIS/src/plugins/georeferencer/qgsgeorefplugingui.cpp:1124:3: error: ‘mActionLocalHistogramStretch’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/src/Quantum-GIS/src/plugins/georeferencer/qgsgeorefplugingui.cpp:1125:3: error: ‘mActionFullHistogramStretch’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [src/plugins/georeferencer/CMakeFiles/georefplugin.dir/qgsgeorefplugingui.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/plugins/georeferencer/CMakeFiles/georefplugin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Bit weird as I've been successfully compiled QGIS trunk on this machine running Ubuntu 12.04.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pierre,

It looks like [this recent commit](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/commit/82a1591d6de56f190d9db17c7991f73f774820ea) may be causing you problems. However, since there have been successful automated builds for Ubuntu since then, I would suggest starting with an empty CMake build directory, pulling in any additional changes from [the QGIS github.com repository](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS), and trying again.

Your compiler is acting like the .ui file for qgsgeorefplugingui.cpp isn't being compiled by Qt to ui_qgsgeorefpluginguibase.h, or that file isn't being included properly.

With my compiler on Mac 10.7.4, GNU 4.2.1, I don't even see a warning for src/plugins/georeferencer/qgsgeorefplugingui.cpp. If the above does not work, you may want to consider cloning a fresh copy of the git repository.

Comment: Thanks - it was a matter of cleaning my Cmake build dir.